# Whatsapp update not happening

Tags: whatsapp, store, app-update

On opening whatsapp, it gives a message Update WhatsApp, on click of it, the windows phone store opens and there is no update button available, it just gives me the option "Share" instead of "Update" and "Cancel". This is happening since past 2 days and I am not able to find a solution.

I can just see on the tile that 52 unread messages are there and I keep getting the notification, but on click of it, it just says "UPDATE WHATSAPP".

Comment: What version do you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

Just Uninstall the app and install the app directly from [whatsapp.com](http://www.whatsapp.com/download/). This may resolve your issue..

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling and then reinstalling the app.

Comment: If I uninstall and reinstall, what abt my chat history, specifically the ones that are unread from past 2 days

Comment: Whatsapp backups the chat, groups everyday at a specific time set by the user, so till the last backup your chats are safe and whatsapp gives you the option to restore but the chats after that wont be restored.

Answer (score 0):

Windows phone are always dependent on internet source...when you are connected to a proper cellular connection or a good Wi-Fi it will get update automatically! 
You don't need to click anything! 
Former solution of uninstalling and reinstalling will install the latest version for sure. But for the purpose you have i.e history. I recommend you to wait for sometime if you can:) or do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Go to review and rate the app. There you can find the button to update.

I also had the same problem due to changing of sim card more than 3 times. It started showing the stuff till I reviewed it and i tried to update but showing me that I need to update it which I think it is caused by my network but I deleted the app totally I will again tomorrow try to download it and see what happens. maybe it will be better if you also delete it and re-install it